# Traversing through Directories in C

Tags: c, unix, posix, dir

I am trying to traverse through a directory whose path is given but the following program is not going inside the directories and is stuck in infinit loop. What is the problem in this code:

```
void func(char path[]);
int main(int argc, char *argv)
{
    char buf[255];
    getcwd(buf,255);
    func(buf);
}

void func(char path[])
{
    DIR *dirp;
    struct stat states;
    struct dirent *direntp;

    dirp=opendir(path);
    chdir(path);

    while((direntp=readdir(dirp))!=NULL)
    {
        if(S_ISDIR(states.st_mode))//true than returns zero
        {
            printf("%s\n",direntp->d_name);
        }
    else
        if(!(strcmp(direntp->d_name,".")||strcmp(direntp->d_name,"..")))// if true retrns zero
        {   
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            func(direntp->d_name);
            chdir("..");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check whether if the node is directory without an auxiliary `states`.`struct dirent` has a field called `d_type`, AND it with `DT_DIR` to test if it is a directory.

Answer (score 1):

You're either missing some code or the issue is the fact that you never populate/update `states`.

Also have another look at this line:

```
if(!(strcmp(direntp->d_name,".")||strcmp(direntp->d_name,"..")))
```

It will never evaluate to a true value as that would require the `direntp->d_name` to be equal to `.` and `..` at the same time (which is simply impossible). I guess you wanted to check with a `&&` here, which would only enter the branch in case your directory name matches either value.

Comment: Sorry that was a typing mistake ! is for the whole comparison

Comment: Not sure I can follow you. You negate the result of the logical or - that's how I read it?

Comment: @Alfred From DeMorgan's Law `!(a || b) == !a && !b`. In your case it will be true only if both `strcmp()` return 0 which is impossible (string must be equal to `"."` and `".."` at the same time).

Comment: Mario is right. You should have a call as below to update state of states: if(stat(currentPath, &states) == -1){
      perror("stat");
      return errno;
    }

Answer (score 0):

In this piece of your code, `states` is not initialized before it is used:

```
struct stat states;
struct dirent *direntp;

dirp=opendir(path);
chdir(path);

while((direntp=readdir(dirp))!=NULL)
{
    if(S_ISDIR(states.st_mode))//true than returns zero
```

I think compiler would warn about that, too, so please switch on warning in your compiler (`-W -Wall` for gcc), and then heed and fix the warnings.